# Включение нескольких тестов в проект CMake

Tags: c++, юнит-тесты, boost

Здравствуйте, не могу разобраться с тем как включить несколько тестов в проект, по одному все прекрасно работает, но а когда их несколько то все ломается... Вот пример:

#### Vector2fTest.cpp

```
// Connects .cpp file, because don't need to
// create a library for testing with .h and .cpp files
#include "Math/Vectors/Vector2f.cpp"

#define BOOST_TEST_MODULE Vector2fTest

#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE(suiteVectors2f)

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(addVectors2f)
{
    float x = 5.0f;
    float y = 10.0f;

    Math::Vector2f currVector2f(x, y);
    Math::Vector2f otherVector2f(x, y);
    currVector2f.add(otherVector2f);

    BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(currVector2f.x, x + x);
    BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(currVector2f.y, y + y);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(subVectors2f)
{
    float x = 3.0f;
    float y = 7.0f;

    Math::Vector2f currVector2f(x, y);
    Math::Vector2f otherVector2f(x, y);
    currVector2f.sub(otherVector2f);

    BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(currVector2f.x, x - x);
    BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(currVector2f.y, y - y);
}

...

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE_END()
```

#### Vector3fTest.cpp

```
// Connects .cpp file, because don't need to
// create a library for testing with .h and .cpp files
#include "Math/Vectors/Vector3f.cpp"

#define BOOST_TEST_MODULE Vector3fTest

#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE(suiteVectors3f)

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(addVectors3f)
{
    float x = 5.0f;
    float y = 10.0f;
    float z = 1.0f;

    Math::Vector3f currVector3f(x, y, z);
    Math::Vector3f otherVector3f(x, y, z);
    currVector3f.add(otherVector3f);

    BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(currVector3f.x, x + x);
    BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(currVector3f.y, y + y);
    BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(currVector3f.z, z + z);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(subVectors3f)
{
    float x = 3.0f;
    float y = 7.0f;
    float z = 1.0f;

    Math::Vector3f currVector3f(x, y, z);
    Math::Vector3f otherVector3f(x, y, z);
    currVector3f.sub(otherVector3f);

    BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(currVector3f.x, x - x);
    BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(currVector3f.y, y - y);
    BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(currVector3f.z, z - z);
}

...

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE_END()
```

#### CMakeLists.txt

```
make_minimum_required (VERSION 3.8)

include_directories (${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/Sources)

set (TESTS Vector3fTest.cpp Vector2fTest.cpp) #MovableObjectTest.cpp)

add_definitions (-DBOOST_TEST_DYN_LINK)

find_package (Boost COMPONENTS unit_test_framework REQUIRED)

add_executable (Test${PROJECT_NAME} ${TESTS})
target_include_directories (${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE 
${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries (Test${PROJECT_NAME} ${Boost_LIBRARIES})

add_test (NAME Vector2fTest COMMAND addVectors2f subVectors2f mulVectors2f divVectors2f)
add_test (NAME Vector3fTest COMMAND addVectors3f subVectors3f mulVectors3f divVectors3f)
```

#### Ошибка

```
CMakeFiles/TestFastEngine.dir/Vector2fTest.cpp.o: In function `init_unit_test()':
/usr/include/boost/test/unit_test_suite.hpp:338: multiple definition of `init_unit_test()'
```

CMakeFiles/TestFastEngine.dir/Vector3fTest.cpp.o:/usr/include/boost/test/unit_test_suite.hpp:338: first defined here
    CMakeFiles/TestFastEngine.dir/Vector2fTest.cpp.o: In function `main':
/usr/include/boost/test/unit_test.hpp:62: multiple definition of`main'
 CMakeFiles/TestFastEngine.dir/Vector3fTest.cpp.o:/usr/include/boost/test/unit_test.hpp:62: first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: собирать их в отдельные исполняемые файлы, не? ЗЫ: предыдущий  (https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/817645/%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d1%81-boost-test) уже решён?

Comment: 50 на 50, хотел спросить по поводу ничего страшного если я .cpp подключаю, вместо того что собирать либу для исходников, просто если .h инклюдить то реализация класса почему-то не включается

Comment: Ну а допустим если я соберу каждый в отдельный исполняемые, как можно будет их пачкой запускать, как например в Java с JUnit

Comment: Подключать .cpp не следует. Если хотите тестировать код из .cpp файла, то из него следует предварительно собрать статическую или динамическую библиотеку и прилинковать ее к тестовому проекту. Ошибка происходит из-за наличия двух директив `BOOST_TEST_MODULE`. Если нужно несколько модулей, то для каждого следует делать отдельный проект.

Comment: подключать cpp — грязновато, но в принципе не страшно и на мелких проектах из 2-3-х файлов допустимо... когда понадобится подключать больше одного — время задуматься о сборке библиотеки... По поводу того как запускать или `make test` по-старинке (не забудь `enable_testing ()` добавить в `CMakeLists.txt`), или `ctest`'ом — умеет и в консоль выводить и  отчёты для web'а генерировать... и много-чего ещё...

Comment: да, по поводу генерации отчётов я промахнулся похоже..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Каждый пакет тестов следует собирать в отдельный исполняемый файл. Примерный `CMakeLists.txt` может выглядеть следующим образом:

```
сmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.8)

find_package (Boost COMPONENTS unit_test_framework REQUIRED)
add_definitions (-DBOOST_TEST_DYN_LINK)
include_directories ( ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/Sources
                      ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})

set (TESTS Vector3fTest Vector2fTest) #MovableObjectTest)

foreach (_test ${TESTS})
  add_executable (${_test} ${_test}.cpp)
  target_link_libraries (${_test} ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
  add_test (NAME ${_test} COMMAND ${_test)
endforeach ()
```

Запускать все тесты пакетом можно с помощью `make test` (если добавить в `CMakeLists.txt` команду `enable_testing ()`) или с помощью утилиты `ctest` bp пакета `cmake`'а. Последняя кроме прочего умеет запускать только определённые тесты по регулярному выражению от имени и делать много-чего ещё.